# How can I prevent a select menu option from being highlighted when it is selected?

Tags: html, css

When the user selects one of the options in a `<select>` menu I don't want it to be highlighted. How can I achieve this?

```
<select id="my_select_menu">
    <option id="1">Option 1</option> // do not highlight when selected
    <option id="2">Option 2</option> // do not highlight when selected
    ....
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your css put this

```
#my_select_menu
{
    outline: none;
}
```